# All Weights Are "1" For Mahalanobis Nearest-Neighbor Matching

Tags: r, causality, matching, mahalanobis

When generating weights using nearest-neighbor matching with Mahalanobis distance, all of my weights for each treated and non-treated unit are "1". Below is my syntax using the `MatchIt` package in R:

```
m_matched <- matchit(pko ~ lnatres + lgdppc + lpop + lmilper,
                     data = merged,
                     method = "nearest",
                     estimand = "ATT",
                     distance = "mahalanobis")

m_matched <- match.data(m_matched)
```

```
> summary(m_matched$weights)

#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#     1       1       1       1       1       1
```

I am not sure why this is the case and I am wondering if anyone has any idea of what error on my part may be causing this. Or is this somehow a part of this method of matching?

Comment: Is there any reason you would expect them to be different from 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing 1:1 matching without replacement, all matched units receive a weight of 1 and all unmatched units receive a weight of 0. `match.data()` removes the unmatched units from the dataset, so all that remains are the units with weights of 1.

How matching weights are computed is explained in the [documentation](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/reference/matchit.html#how-matching-weights-are-computed) for `matchit()`. When matching for the ATT, treated units receive a weight of 1, and matched control units receive a weight of $p_i/(1-p_i)$, where $p_i$ is the proportion of units in the pair that unit $i$ is in that are treated. For 1:1 matching, every pair has 2 units, 1 of which is treated, so $p_i = .5$. Applying that formula (which is the same formula used for computing ATT weights with propensity score weighting), all matched control units receive a weight of 1.